# Templated byte streaming

Tags: c++, template, stream

I often have the need to take some type and stream it to something as a sequence of character byte values, so I came up with this to accomplish the task:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

/// This provides a way of getting the byte representation of an
/// object of underlying type T.
///
/// This is an alternative to memcopying bytes into a string, stream,
/// character array...
template<typename inT, typename outT = char>
struct byte_streamer
{
    byte_streamer(inT ref)
      : data(ref)
    {}
    const inT data;
    outT placeholder;
};

template<typename inT, typename outT>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& strm, const byte_streamer<inT, outT> val)
{
    std::copy(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&val.data),
              reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&val.data) + sizeof(inT),
              std::ostream_iterator<decltype(val.placeholder)>(strm, ""));
    return strm;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Here's the bytes of 42 copied directly: " << byte_streamer(42) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Here's the bytes of 42 copied as their numerical values: "
              << byte_streamer<int, int>(42);
}
```

You can [run it online on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/53ae2f69f838dc4f) or just look at the output here:

```
Here's the bytes of 42 copied directly: *
Here's the bytes of 42 copied as their numerical values: 42000
```

Answer (score 5):

Well, there are a few points:

1. You make a copy of the object you output. That can be costly, impossible, or have undesirable side-effects. Use a constant reference instead.
2. There are essentially two modes for your byte_streamer: Output the raw bytes, or output as decimal values for each byte.
   The latter is broken as each byte is variable-width (1-3 digits for octets), and there is no separator.
3. You use the member `placeholder` only to convey the type `outT` to other code. Why not use a typedef instead, avoiding inefficiency and painful contortions?
4. Only use `std::endl` if you want to flush the stream. Otherwise, using `'\n'` and avoiding that extra-work is simply far more efficient.
5. It's really unusual not to end the programs output with a line-break. Wonder where the prompt will end up if called from a terminal...

Imho, the only useful outputs would be hex-dump and raw-bytes.

```
class dump_hex_t {
    const void* p = nullptr;
    std::size_t s = 0;
public:
    constexpr dump_hex_t() noexcept = default;
    constexpr dump_hex_t(const void* p, std::size_t s) noexcept : p(p), s(s) {}

    template <class CharT, class Traits>
    friend auto& operator<<(std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>& os, dump_hex_t x) {
        ... // Dump as hex-digits however you like
    }
};

template <class T>
constexpr dump_hex_t dump_hex(const T& x) noexcept
{ return { std::addressof(x), sizeof x }; }

template <class T>
constexpr std::string_view dump_raw(const T& x) noexcept
{ return { (const char*)std::addressof(x), sizeof x }; }
```

Comment: Why the unnecessary default constructor - the class's only purpose is to be used by `dump_hex()`, right? And why manually construct the sentry in the inserter?

Comment: Thank you for reviewing my code.  Regarding your points:  1) yup.  2)ahhh... now I realize in my attempt to create a minimally sized reviewable example, I did a poor example explaining what I need to accomplish -- probably because of a poor understanding thereof.  I'll have to meditate on that.  3)  I don't follow what you mean by using a typedef instead.  Can you elaborate?

Comment: @indi: I did the default-ctor just because I could. And I manually construct the sentry because that's implementing a formatted stream-inserter, and those should do that.

Comment: @Spacemoose I elaborated in an edit.

Comment: There is no need to construct the sentry object if you're just using the stream's functions; they all do it internally anyway. Presumably the "..." will be something like `copy_n(static_cast<uchar const*>(x.p), x.s, ostream_inserter<uint>{os, " "});`, which does `os.operator<<(uint)`, which constructs the sentry.

Comment: @indi: That would be very inefficient, though it might look somewhat acceptably with the right stream-format (0-padded, width-2 hexadecimal). Still, line-breaks would be nice, maybe blocking 8 bytes...

Comment: What do you think would a more efficient version look like? Honestly, the implementation I'd use in practice would be basically that but using a stringstream to construct the entire output with, then just do `return os << stringstream.rdbuf();`.

Comment: @indi Probably manually assemble each line in an automatic buffer, and then insert it with `rdbuf().xsputn()`. All the sentry-instantiation, and format-options-handling for each byte isn't actually needed.

Comment: I suppose that's a legitimate implementation, but my problem is that it is not the only one, nor even the most obvious/easiest, and *most* implementations (especially those a newbie would think of) won't need the sentry. Adding the sentry as if it is necessary boilerplate is only going to cause confusion.